# Difference between using fully qualified name and import in Java

Tags: java, import, inline

Are there any differences using an "inline import" (a fully qualified name) and normal import in terms of performance, memory, compile-time, etc. in Java?

```
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
```

and

```
import java.io.File;
...
   chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
```

Comment: There is no difference, only the second solution is more readable. You should only use `inline imports` if there is a conflict of classes otherwise.

Comment: I would suggest you use the second one for better readability. And worry about performance when you have measurements what performs bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main thing you should focus in is readability. I find the second one more readable.

In rare cases, I prefer the second approach. Let's consider the following scenario: For some reason, I wrote a class and named it `File`. I typed `File file = new File(...)` and my IDE auto-imported the `java.io.File` for me. But I don't want that kind of object, I want *my* `File` class. So instead of importing the correct class, I prefer inline-import it, just that other users won't get confused with the Java's `File` class.

Regarding the performance, they're *exactly* the same, and here's the proof -

This is the bytecode generated for the first snippet:

```
public class java8.tests.General {
  public java8.tests.General();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class javax/swing/JFileChooser
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method javax/swing/JFileChooser."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: new           #4                  // class java/io/File
      12: dup
      13: ldc           #5                  // String .
      15: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/io/File."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method javax/swing/JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory:(Ljava/io/File;)V
      21: return
}
```

This is the bytecode for the second:

```
public class java8.tests.General {
  public java8.tests.General();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class javax/swing/JFileChooser
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method javax/swing/JFileChooser."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: new           #4                  // class java/io/File
      12: dup
      13: ldc           #5                  // String .
      15: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/io/File."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method javax/swing/JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory:(Ljava/io/File;)V
      21: return
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No both are exactly same in the terms of performance, memory, compile-time. The only difference between them is that normal import save your typing efforts and it's more readable that' it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are importing classes of the *same name* in *one class*, you are able to explicitly tell which one to use where (full class name):

```
import java.io.File;
...
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(".")); // java.io.File

new org.yourpackage.File("sdfsdf");         // org.yourpackage.File
```

Answer (score 3):

It only matters in following case,

If you want to use a class which is available in multiples packages.
i.e. Date class is available in java.util & java.sql

You can import one of above class at start of program, and use qualified syntax for another one.

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't affect performance of your code.
Import statements make your code more readable because you're not writing all your package name.
But sometimes, you have a conflict of ClassNames, then it is advisable to use qualified names.

Answer (score 1):

In java classes are always referenced by their fully qualified name in the final bytecode. It happens the very first time when an object of class is created (or a static member of the class is accessed).

That said, `import` is used by the compiler to access classes by their unqualified name (`MyClass` instead of `mypackage.MyClass`).

So there is a 0 difference between importing the class, or writing explicitly the fully qualified name - it's just matter of readability, saves some typing and helps to prevent clashing between classes with a same name.