# What do the periods in "java.util.Scanner" in Java refer to?

Tags: java, syntax

I am guessing it refers to a directory hierarchy and if so how does it work exactly?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html Java source is typically organized in a directory hierarchy matching the package naming, but there is no requirement for it to be so.

Comment: `java` is a package, `java.util` is a subpackage of `java`, and `java.util.Scanner` is a class in the `java.util` package. Package hierarchies may be mapped to directory hierarchies, but this is not required by the java language specification

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965977/difference-between-using-fully-qualified-name-and-import-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The periods are used as separators for the package structure.
The class `Scanner` lies within the package `util` which lies itself in the package `java`.

The packages are represented by directories in the file system, the `Scanner` class is a `Scanner.java` file in it.